# Wildfly HA/LB in domain mode and aws Elastic Load balancer

Tags: java, load-balancing, wildfly-8, java-ee-7, high-availability

Given wildfly HA in domain mode cluster which allows administrator to just deploy on the host-controller, and lets say all domain mode are deployed on aws, will this suffice for LB? or would one still relegate to actual LB using aws elastic load-balancing. If not, would the generic wildfly HA/LB suffice in this case?

I am trying to figure out which is the best scenario for me. wildfly HA with session replication sounds just awesome, and is in the realm of what i am looking for. i am also trying to avoid several single deployments, and allow the domain host controller to take care of the rest of slave deployments.

My question really is, if i go this way with wildfly clustering, do i really need a separate LB, say aws Elastic Load Balancer?